# Laptop Screen Blinks

Tags: release-juno, graphic-drivers, nvidia

My laptop's screen blinks and can't enter the login screen, this happens when the laptop is suspended or locked, I think this is because I use the nvidia driver. is it here that can help me?

dell inspiron-3421 with Nvidia GT625M

Answer (score 2):

There's workaround on this link:

https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues/166#issuecomment-437144185

Comment: I've tried this method, but it really doesn't work. I just uninstalled nvidia diver.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a manual trick/bypass for nvidia graphics driven laptops till an official solution comes up!*
The simple way to handle this is to press the following keys at the same time immediately you resume from suspension or lock ; **CTRL** + **ALT** + **DELETE**